# Spring 4 Migration -ClassCastException : cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, classcastexception, spring-4

I am getting this Exception while upgrading from Spring 3.0 to 4.0

I updated the deprecated classes with this [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html)

`DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping,AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` with `RequestMappingHandlerMapping ,RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: AuditingController$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$992fb2c8 cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod 

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
```

Here is beans definition

```
<bean name="handlerAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
            <property name="messageConverters">
        <array>
            ....

           ....
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my testcase calling this function.

```
  handlerAdapter.handle(request, response, controller);
```

which calls `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter`

```
return handleInternal(request, response, (HandlerMethod) handler);
```

here it fails to cast the controller to `HandlerMethod`

Comment: Your testcase is wrong, handling `@RequestMethod` annotated methods has changed considerable from `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` to `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. It now points directly to the method to invoke (i.e. the `HandlerMethod` ) so putting your full controller in there isn't going to work anymore,

Comment: Why are you even testing Spring classes? You should be testing your `@Controller` beans. These `HandlerAdapter` objects are used by Spring's `DispatcherServlet` stack (and MVC configuration). You should assume they work and test your own code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I am testing my controller itself. Not testing spring classes. I am using `MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpServletResponse, HandlerAdapter` and testing the response data

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you shouldn't. The whole point of using Spring MVC is to go through the `DispatcherServlet`. You're not really testing your controllers if you are going around the `DispatcherServlet`. Just set up a `MockMvc` object from your MVC configuration and test your requests through there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working now. As mentioned in this [link](https://spring.io/blog/2012/11/12/spring-framework-3-2-rc1-spring-mvc-test-framework), I need to update my controller test cases to use

```
WebApplicationContext,MockMvc & RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
```

instead of

```
MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpServletResponse & HandlerAdapter.
```